# AWS CodeBuild issues with apk build

Tags: react-native

I am using AWS CodeBuild to trigger the apk build for react native app. Facing issue with android home not found. I am pulling the source code from GitHub and in buildspec.yml have passed "apt update && apt install android-sdk"

Comment: More details please.  What issues?  What is it doing that you do not expect and what do you expect it to do if it works?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the CodeBuild curated image, the Android curated images will have the Android SDK pre-installed and ANDROID_HOME environment variable available.